# QGIS 2.81. Why can i only see my whole polygon and nothing if i zoom in

Tags: polygon, scale, visibility

I have a polygon layer with one object. It is a flood inundation map. I could see my layer all the time in every scale factor. From one moment to the other it changed and know it is only visible if i zoom out and the whole polygon is visible. If i zoom in and only a part of the polygon should be visible, there is nothing. What can I do? I tried everything with layer properties -> general ->scale dependent visibility, but even if i uncheck it, the Layer is not visible.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the shapefile's spatial index is stale or corrupt. Based [on this technical article from ESRI](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/24610), the shapefile's spatial index maybe corrupted. The technical article offers a solution that may help you solve the problem. Please have a look at it.

Another option is to try to export your data to a new shapefile, and see if that solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it didn't work. I have the folowing fileendings for my shapefile: *.dfb; *.prj; *.qix; *.qpj; *.shp; *.shx. In the article you mentioned the deleted the files with SBX and SBN extensions. I don t have them. But i tried to start with only the three obligated files (shp; dbf; shx) but i had stil the same problem.

The second option you mentioned i tried as well but no sucess.

Comment: Try to load your data into new QGIS project and check if the problem still exist.

Comment: Yes i tried and also with another version of Qgis. Stil the same problem

Comment: @Isi - Perhaps you can upload your shapefile to a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: I have not the permission to do that.

Comment: Try current QGIS version 2.14.1. If there happens to be a bug in 2.8.1 it won't be fixed anyway.

Comment: QGIS does not read the .sbn, sbx files (ESRI only). It reads the .qix index, created by OGR.

Comment: @klewis - thank you for this comment. I don't know that. But if i delete the *.qix nothings changes. it is still not working.